# Can't update object property when running setInterval

Tags: javascript

I was trying to change the property for the objects inside `this._keys`. The method I am using worked fine to change the property but the problem is I have an if statement that decides if the property gets changed or not and that if statement checks if a variable is equal to a string. That variable is dynamic so I have to `setInterval` to keep on updating the data. But when I setInterval I cant update the property of the object anymore. I get the error `Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'forward')`. Why can't I change the property while updating the data? I have commented on my code to better point out the problem. Any help on why this occurs and how to fix it is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
const currentKeylogW, currentKeylogA,
  currentKeylogD, currentKeylogS = a dynamic data;


class BasicCharacterControllerInput2 {
  constructor() {
    this._Init();
  }
  
  
  _Init() {

    this._keys = {
      forward: false,
      backward: false,
      left: false,
      right: false,
      space: false,
      shift: false,
      shiftForward: false,
    };

    //this has no error but currentKeylog's variables are not being updtes so its useless
    if (currentKeylogW == '"w"') {
      this._keys.forward = true;
    } else if (currentKeylogA == '"a"') {
      this._keys.left = true;
    } else if (currentKeylogD == '"d"') {
      this._keys.left = true;
    } else if (currentKeylogS == '"s"') {
      this._keys.right = true;
    } else if (currentKeylogW == '"!w"') {
      this._keys.forward = false;
    } else if (currentKeylogA == '"!a"') {
      this._keys.left = false;
    } else if (currentKeylogD == '"!d"') {
      this._keys.left = false;
    } else if (currentKeylogS == '"!s"') {
      this._keys.right = false;
    }


    //updates currentKeylog's variables but can't set forward,.. properties
    setInterval(function() {

      if (currentKeylogW == '"w"') {
        this._keys.forward = true;
      } else if (currentKeylogA == '"a"') {
        this._keys.left = true;
      } else if (currentKeylogD == '"d"') {
        this._keys.left = true;
      } else if (currentKeylogS == '"s"') {
        this._keys.right = true;
      } else if (currentKeylogW == '"!w"') {
        this._keys.forward = false;
      } else if (currentKeylogA == '"!a"') {
        this._keys.left = false;
      } else if (currentKeylogD == '"!d"') {
        this._keys.left = false;
      } else if (currentKeylogS == '"!s"') {
        this._keys.right = false;
      }

    }, 500)

  }
}
```

Comment: Where is this `_Init` function? This is invalid JS code.

Comment: `setInterval(() => {`…`}, 500);`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon how is this invalid??

Comment: yep the setInterval was the problem but the code is valid JS

Comment: You have correctly added the missing `}` yourself, and _now_ you’re asking me how this is invalid? You can verify the validity for yourself by using tools like ESLint or by simply running the code.

Comment: so thats why you said not valid oh i though you said the whole code. Thanks for the help though